# Where does Spring Roo save its information?

Tags: spring-roo

What I like to know is where *Spring roo* stores the execution properties after executing commands like the *topLevelPackage*. I know there is a *log.roo* file that lists all executed commands, but that is definitely not the place *roo* reads its properties from during any file or package modifications like the above mentioned *topLevelPackage*.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, roo doesn't store any information in any roo specific files. Rather it finds information in the actual project files.  The topLevelPackage is inferred from the pom.xml for example. There are a few exceptions, for example the dbre module does keep an xml file.